# Load elements from datatable(jsf) to collection

Tags: java, jsf

I have a datatable on jsf page with next columns: product name, price and input field for product amount. By click on the button I should load elements from datatable to collection where product amount is more than 0(method addCups). 
How to create it?
Thank you.

Managed Bean

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class OrderBean extends SpringBeanAutowiringSupport {
@Autowired
private OrderDAO orderDAO;

@Autowired
private OrderPositionDAO orderPositionDAO;


private Map<Long, Integer> selectedItems = new HashMap<>();

private Integer quantityOfCups;

public Map<Long, Integer> getSelectedItems() {
    return selectedItems;
}

public void setSelectedItems(Map<Long, Integer> selectedItems) {
    this.selectedItems = selectedItems;
}

public Integer getQuantityOfCups() {
    return quantityOfCups;
}

public void setQuantityOfCups(Integer quantityOfCups) {
    this.quantityOfCups = quantityOfCups;
}


public void addCups(Long id, Integer numOfCups){
    if(numOfCups > 0){
        selectedItems.put(id, numOfCups);
    }
    if(numOfCups == 0){
        selectedItems.remove(id);
    }
    System.out.println(selectedItems);
}
```

JSF page

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:form>
<p:dataTable value="#{coffeeBean.allCoffee}" var="coffee">
    <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{coffee.coffeeName}"/>
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{coffee.costForCup}"/>
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <p:inputText value="#{orderBean.quantityOfCups}"/>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
    <h:commandButton value="add cups" action="#{orderBean.addCups(coffee.id, orderBean.quantityOfCups)}"/>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are number of ways to achieve this but, with minimal modifications of your posted code, you can achieve it on following way:

- add one hidden data table column with your coffee ID and define `widgetVar` property of data table ,
- use JavaScript method to iterate through data table values and pick up coffee ID-quantity pairs,
- use `p:remoteCommand` to send array of coffee cups as JSON string to backing bean
- inside bean method parse passed JSON string and add/remove coffee cups to/from your order

**Your xhtml page `h:form` would look like this**

```
<h:form>
    <p:dataTable widgetVar="dataTableWidget" value="#{coffeeBean.allCoffee}" var="cofee">
        <p:column style="display:none">
            <h:outputText value="#{coffee.id}"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="name">
            <h:outputText value="#{coffee.coffeeName}"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="price">
            <h:outputText value="#{coffee.costForCup}"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="quantity">
            <p:inputText/>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>

    <p:commandButton value="Add cups" type="button" onclick="collectOrderFromTable()"/>
    <p:remoteCommand name="sendToOrderBean" actionListener="#{orderBean.addCups}"/>
</h:form>
```

with added java script

```
            <script>
//<![CDATA[
                function collectOrderFromTable() {
                    var coffeeCups = [];
                    //get table rows
                    var tableRows = PF('dataTableWidget').tbody[0].childNodes;
                    //loop through rows    
                    for (i = 0; i < tableRows.length; i++) {
                        //get cells of current row
                        var cells = tableRows[i].cells;
                        //get value of hidden ID column
                        var id = cells[0].innerText;
                        //get quantity from input field
                        var quantity = cells[3].firstChild.value;
                        //add new item to array
                        coffeeCups.push({id: id, quantity: quantity});
                    }
                    console.log("Coffee cups", JSON.stringify(coffeeCups));
                    sendToOrderBean([{name: 'coffeeCups', value: JSON.stringify(coffeeCups)}]);
                }
//]]>
            </script>
```

**Method `addCups` in your `OrderBean` would be like this:**

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
//...
//...

public void addCups() {
    //get string passed from xhtml page
    String values = (String) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("coffeCups");
    //parse JSON string to List
    List<CoffeeQuantity> coffeCups = (ArrayList<CoffeeQuantity>) new Gson().fromJson(values, new TypeToken<ArrayList<CoffeeQuantity>>() {}.getType());
    for (CoffeeQuantity cq : coffeCups) {
        System.out.println("Coffee id: " + cq.getId() + ", Quantity:" + cq.getQuantity());
        if (cq.getQuantity()>0){
            selectedItems.put(cq.getId(), cq.getQuantity());
        }else{
            selectedItems.remove(cq.getId());
        }
    }
}
```

where `CoffeeQuantity` is helper class to make JSON string parsing easier

```
public class CoffeQuantity {
    int id;
    Integer quantity;

    //getters and setters...

}
```